# How can I slow my network performance for *ajax* requests to debug?

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging

Our application is ajax heavy.
Our server logs show issues with various pages but we're unable to reproduce them locally (using the internet but our high speed connection that is).

How can I slow my network connection down to reflect real world low bandwidth environments, specifically for ajax requests so that when I am testing the slowness doesn't affect the main HTML page load, graphics, etc.

Comment: In Chrome's Dev tools, Device mode, there is network throttling selection.

Comment: Maybe you can find an old AOL cd lying around :-)

Comment: Ironically I have many shrink wrapped 'free internet AOL!' CD mail items for my eventual museum of the stuff that is never saved ;)

Comment: It's not free ($29.95), but I've successfully used [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) in the past. It throttles your bandwidth for all applications (or if you wish, just specific ones). Their lite version is $19.95

Comment: Searched and searched chrome dev tools and not finding it.  Please show where it is

Comment: (Trial version of) NetBalancer might help.

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate various network bandwidth conditions in the Chrome dev tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode - this will throttle everything though, not just AJAX requests...

Use the icon between the magnifying glass and the word "Elements" as shown here:

[image]

Comment: @MichaelDurrant On my Chrome the throttling is [next to the "disable cache" button](http://i.imgur.com/XFVWn4V.png).

Comment: Ah, good to know it can be in different places!  Thanks for pointing that out!